# save data pointers

Tags: c++, vector, copy

I have a function `uint32_t* getDataP(uint idx);`,
I have no access to the code of the function.
I need to implement a code ,which calls the function with different `idx` arguments
and saves the results in the vector.
What is the better way to save it in the `vector<uint32_t>` or `vector<uint32_t*>`?
If I decide to save it as `vector<uint32_t*> savedData`,is the following implementation is OK?:

```
for (uint i = 0; i < 10;++ i) {
   dataP = getDataP(i);
   savedData.push_back(dataP);
}
```

Need I perform a deep copy of dataP ?or the above is sufficient?

Comment: What type of data is it? array? object?

Comment: Depends. Where does the returned pointer point to? Static memory? `new`-allocated memory? `malloc`'d memory?

Comment: That depends on what you *want*. Do you want `savedData` to point to the *same* object, or should it store its own copy?

Comment: @larsmans - I don`t know.just have an API of the function

Comment: @jalf - It is not matter

Comment: If it doesn't matter, then why are you asking? Both of your options are valid. Neither of them is "wrong". If you don't know what you want your code to *do*, then how do you expect anyone to help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you save only the pointer, who will be responsible for cleaning up, you or the library ? And is the memory pointed to going to be available for the entire lifetime of your code ?

I would say go with vector<uint32_t>, as it's safer, but I don't really know what your application is doing.

You loop would then become:

```
for (uint i = 0; i < 10;++ i) {
   dataP = getDataP(i);
   savedData.push_back(*dataP);
}
```

Comment: You need to understand the ownership semantics of the returned pointer no matter how you save it.

Comment: Yes John, but what semantic can you get from an uint32_t ? Without knowing any better, I can only suggest what I think is safer.

Comment: You need to read the documentation for `uint32_t* getDataP(uint idx);`  Even if it is safe to store the `uint32`'s by value, if you leak the pointers that `getDataP` gave you because it expected you to take ownership of it, but you didn't, then your code has a bug.

Comment: I fully agree with you. But those pointers might just point to to an array allocated on the stack, and deleting those pointers would kill your app on the spot. What would you do then ? It's a rhetorical question, the point being we're not given sufficient information; however if we had to take a stab at it, std::vector<T> is more likely to be correct than std::vector<T*>, especially when the OP cannot provide a rationale as to why it is stored by pointer.